# ASP.Net core uploading database .mdf file to somee.com

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web-hosting, iis-express

I failed to upload the database file (.mdf) to [somee](http://www.somee.com) web host. I got this error:

[image: image from somee.com]

I don't have a folder called on my computer called "dzsqls" as it says,
I searched for the problem, but I couldn't solve it. I tried to generate the database script, but it doesn't work too, as it says:

> syntax error near ':'.

It sounds like a security error. Any help?

I am still new to ASP.Net core, and I cannot find great community to solve such problems.

Comment: This question is off-topic on StackOverflow: *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.* Please post only question with a concrete programming related problems. For issues with your host, contact your service provider

Comment: it's not about hosting , it's about security issues with IIS server 
i am giving an example with somee.com but it's a general error .

Comment: In your case its related to the specific webhost. Contact them, this aren't support forums. And besides that, you said it yourself its about IIS not about programming. Try SuperUsers or ServerFault which is for administration related questions

Comment: Please also take the time to copy/paste your error rather than screenshot it. You are correct in stating it's a security issue but incorrect in thinking it can be solved based on the info provided.

Comment: i thought providing a screenshot would be better to read 
though u don't have a solution for that problem /

Comment: You need to upload full .bak file. You cant only .mdf file as it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Grant permissions to NETWORK SERVICE user. Modify permissions within the folder.

Comment: how can i do that ? i don't have a folder with that name 
i am sorry for this stupid question but i am still newbie at asp.net